# Play more than 2 videos on videojs with javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, video.js

I've searched a lot for this answer, but I somehow couldn't find it.
Well, the webhosting I'm using right now has an upload limit of 120mb, and some videos I need to host are way bigger than that. A couple ideas came to mind, the 1st being to split the videos up into parts and seemlessly playing them after one another with VideoJS using javascript code.

The second idea was still splitting the videos, but somehow connecting them into 1 "src:" tag so that VideoJS can just be used like it was 1 video.

The second idea seemed impossible, so I went with the first, knowing 0 javascript.
I managed to piece together some code that makes it able to play 2 videos fine, but when the third one is added, it acts weird.
It instead of going to the second video at the end of the 1st one, it goes to the last (in this case, 3rd).

How can I fix this?

code I'm using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        var count=1;
    var player=document.getElementById('test');
    player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) 
        { e = window.event; }
        player.src="test2.mp4";
        }
{
var e = document.getElementById("test");
player.id = "test2";
}
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
        var count=1;
    var player=document.getElementById('test2');
    player.addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);

    function myHandler(e) {
        if(!e) 
        { e = window.event; }
        player.src="test3.mp4";
        }
{
var e = document.getElementById("test2");
player.id = "test3";
}
</script>
```

**keep in mind I know nothing about javascript**

Answer (score 0):

All the variable and function declarations in `<script>` tags go to the global scope.

For example, the second script tag shares the same scope as the first script tag:

```
<body>
    <script>
        var foo = "Hello";
    </script>

    <script>
        console.log(foo); // "Hello"
    </script>
</body>
```

So what you're doing in your code is declaring everything twice, so your second myHandler declaration is overwriting your first one.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not really set with only that info... How would I be able to change the code for it to be working the way I want to?

Comment: I suggest a beginning/moderate course in Javascript and programming before attempting this problem. Otherwise, it would be a waste of my time to try to explain and a waste of yours to try to understand without knowing the fundamentals first.